# Context menu in GridView Android

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have `GridView`:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

// Instance of ImageAdapter Class
final String [] imageNames = {"knee_kg","knee_ks","knee_kp","knee_kg_90", 
                              "pipe_knee", "cover", "funnel", "crater"};
Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[imageNames.length];
for (int i = 0; i<imageNames.length; i++){
    Integer resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageNames[i], "drawable", 
                                                 getPackageName());
    mThumbIds[i] = resID;
}
```

and `OnItemCliclListener`:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        Class clazz = null;
        String className = imageNameToUpper(imageNames[position]);

        try {
            clazz = Class.forName("com.example.pipecalculator.activities." + className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intentClass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), clazz);
        startActivity(intentClass);
    }
});
```

I want create Context menu only on two item click: `"knee_ks"`,`"knee_kp"`. 
On the other is to be:

```
Intent intentClass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), clazz);
startActivity(intentClass);
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.
You should use `int position` :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                    if (position == 0 || position == 2 /*and other, or just: position < 5*/)
                    { 
                       //Code for positio 0 and 2
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //Code for othe positions
                    }
                }   
            });
```

Use [this example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-context-enabled-grid-view-layout-for-android/722/) for showing context menu.

Comment: I want create context menu only for position 0 and 2

Comment: So it's like you want.

Comment: I don't understand, now it's like when click position 0 or 2 open clazz name changed.

Comment: Just edit code in if (position == 0 || position == 2) {/*remove all, or add what should be if you will click on 0, 2 position*/}.

Comment: How call context menu from:public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {}

Comment: Ok, I got it. You should use this example: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-context-enabled-grid-view-layout-for-android/722/

Answer (score 2):

First Register your **gridView** for context menu

```
 registerForContextMenu(grid);
```

and then **override a function**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    GridView gv = (GridView) v;
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
            if(!(position==0 || position==2))
             {
             menu.close();
             )
}
```

**Context Menu Listener**

```
     @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   return true;             
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an old topic but I faced the same issue and would like to drop what works for me. Based on @Abhishek proposition, what I did is just replace the `menu.close()` statement by `menu.clear()` and voilà! the contextual appears only on position 0 and 2.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
            if(!(position==0 || position==2)){
                   menu.clear();
             }
}
```